# Print only the 1st page of emails from eBay & PayPal by default

Tags: microsoft-outlook, printing, vba, default-settings

I buy a lot of stuff off eBay for work and have to print the order confirmation and PayPal receipt emails from Outlook to give to Accounts. Every time, I have to change `Page range` to `1`, because there is always a 2nd page with a line or 2 of rubbish on it - wasting paper. Others in my office more forgetful though, and just click `Print`.

Is it possible to set Outlook to print only the 1st page of emails from eBay and PayPal, by default? Maybe using VBA?

The two machines we use run Outlook 2003 and 2013 respectively.

Comment: No, IMHO it is not possible.

Comment: Is the question really "is it possible to do this with VBa"?

Comment: What about duplex printing, you would just waste a tiny amount of ink.